# How to prevent command line wildcard processor from evaluating short file names

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, batch, wildcards

I'm developing a batch file within which I'm using the following pattern:

*.res

I want to select all files with the extension **.res**, but this pattern is matching files with an extension of **.resources** also.

In other words, it acts like I'm specifying ***.res*** but I'm not.

Is there a way I can prevent the command line from evaluating short 8.3 filenames?

Comment: There is a registry option to disable this globally.

Comment: I found a way to disable the generation of short file names:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210638

Is this what you are referring to?

It doesn't appear to affect *existing* short file names, however.

Comment: Related: [`DEL *1.*` deletes all files in folder](http://superuser.com/q/370300/397839)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to iterate manually and exclude those files that don't match, for example like this:

```
for %%f in (*.res) do if [%%~xf]==[.res] (
    rem do something with %%f here
)
```