# DEL *1.* deletes all files in folder

Tags: windows, command-line, wildcards

I'm trying to delete all files that end with the number one, but for some reason it is deleting all of the files in the folder.

The command I'm using is

```
DEL *1.*
```

It works when I use a letter like

```
DEL *e.*
```

but when I use a number everything is deleted.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes

Comment: The fact that one question asks about `dir` and wildcard behaviour and the other question asks about `del` and the same wildcard behaviour doesn't actually make them different questions, Nifle.  The _behaviour of the wildcards in matching names_ is the core of the question.  It's frequently asked, and this duplicate is almost in canonical form.  grawity answered it twice before. [So have](http://superuser.com/questions/238900/248976#248976) [I](http://superuser.com/questions/63777/248977#248977). [These are all duplicates](http://superuser.com/questions/179479/251220#251220).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Windows keeps an [8.3 file name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) for every file to ensure compatility.

So if you have the files

```
test1.ext
test2.ext
test3.long
```

the last file gets stored with the alternative name

```
TEST3~1.LON
```

thus matching the pattern `*1.*`.

You can execute `dir /x` to see all 8.3 file names.

**Fixes**:

- To strip all files in the directory `directory` of their 8.3 name, execute

  ```
  fsutil 8dot3name strip directory
  ```
- To strip all files in the directory `directory` of their 8.3 name, including those in subdirectories, execute

  ```
  fsutil 8dot3name strip directory /s
  ```
- To disable 8.3 file names on the drive `drive:` (only affects newly created files), execute

  ```
  fsutil 8dot3name set drive: 1
  ```
- To disable 8.3 file names altogether (only affects newly created files), execute

  ```
  fsutil 8dot3name set 1
  ```

For the complete syntax, execute

```
fsutil 8dot3name strip & fsutil 8dot3name set
```

Furhter information:

- [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces: Short vs. Long Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#short_vs._long_names)
- [How Windows Generates 8.3 File Names from Long File Names](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982)

Comment: Which versions of Windows do these apply to?

Comment: @jprete: Long file names (and thus, wildcard quirkiness) exist since NT 3.5 in 1994. `fsutil` was introduced in XP, if I remember correctly.